# qscintilla python binding issue

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qscintilla

Attempting to follow the QSCintilla instructions re Python bindings for PyQT5

```
Python Bindings

The Python bindings are in the Python directory. You must have either PyQt v4 or v5 already installed. QScintilla must also already be built and installed.

The configure, build and install the bindings for PyQt v4, run:

    python configure.py
    make
    make install On Windows (and depending on the compiler you are using) you may need to run nmake rather than make.

If you want to build the bindings for PyQt v5 then pass –pyqt=PyQt5 as an argument to configure.py.
```

But when I run the below command it complains about PyQt5 not being installed

```
python configure.py --qmake=/users/marklloyd/Qt/5.8/clang_64/bin/qmake --pyqt=PyQt5
Error: Unable to import PyQt5.QtCore. Make sure PyQt5 is installed
```

If I run brew info I can see the dependency is OK

```
brew info qscintilla2

qscintilla2: stable 2.10 (bottled) Port to Qt of the Scintilla editing component https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/intro /usr/local/Cellar/qscintilla2/2.10 (135 files, 6.9MB) *   Poured from bottle on 2017-03-21 at 13:54:46 From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/qscintilla2.rb
==> Dependencies Required: qt5 ✔, sip --with-python3 ✔, pyqt5 ✔
==> Requirements Recommended: python3 ✔ Optional: python ✔
==> Options
--with-plugin   Build the Qt Designer plugin
--with-python   Build Python bindings
--without-python3   Do not build Python3 bindings
```

this is OSX 10.12.3 FYI and I am more than happy to admit I'm not an expert at this level of stuff at all.

I'm trying to get QScintilla working so I can get PyMakr from Pycom installed and working

```
Pymakr-master marklloyd$ python install.py  
Checking dependencies  
Python Version: 2.7.12  
Found PyQt5  
Found pyuic5  
Sorry, please install QScintilla2 and
its PyQt5/PyQt4 wrapper.  
Error: cannot import name Qsci
```

Anyone else suffered similar issues?

To answer Barrys comment

pip3 install QScintilla returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: 
QScintilla in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python‌​3.6/site-packages 
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5>=5.7.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python‌​3.6/site-packages (from QScintilla) 
Requirement already satisfied: sip<4.20,>=4.19 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python‌​3.6/site-packages (from PyQt5>=5.7.1->QScintilla)
```

pip3 install pyqt5

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: sip<4.20,>=4.19 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pyqt5)
```

Comment: Why not install the package with PIP?

Comment: @BarryScott - added results of pip install to original post for you

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm not sure if this can help. I'm working on a Windows 10 pc, and I got problems installing QScintilla recently. I never figured out the real reason, but I got it working as described in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218064/pyqt5-5-8-2-doesnt-function-on-windows-10